# rectangle equation

Tags: kotlin

I'm a beginner with Kotlin and in this example given to me. it is quite confusing. Here is the code I have done for this:

```
import kotlin.math.sqrt

class Rectangle(val length: Double, val width: Double){


fun main(){
  print("Length: ")
  val length = input()
  print("Width: ")
  val width = input()
  val rect = Rectangle(length,width)
  rect.recDetails()
  print("\nNew area: ")
  var area = input()
  rect.area = area
  rect.recDetails()
}

private fun input() = readLine()!!.toDouble()
```

Comment: `user will enter a new area and I need to solve for its length and width.` How will you get new length and width with area? You need to fix one thing and only then you can solve for the other

Comment: When the user enters a new area, should the ratio between width/length stay constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that user can input new area and we need to recalculate the length and width, the first step would be to make them `var`.

After that, the only thing required now is calculating the new length and width when a new area is set. With some basic maths, you can figure out that:

```
Given area A, original length L and original width W:
newLength = sqrt(L*A/W) and newWidth = sqrt(W*A/L)   // keeping the L/W ratio fixed
```

Just use these in the `area` setter

```kotlin
set(value: Double) {
    field = value
    val newLength = sqrt(value * length / width)
    val newWidth = sqrt(value * width / length)
    length = newLength
    width = newWidth
}
```

Although I don't like modifying getters/setters for such calculations, its better to create a proper function for updating area. But since you specifically asked for the getter/setter approach, here it is.